# Change default keyboard shortcuts for Putty

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, putty

I frequently user <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> for page-up in `vim`. I started using PuTTY Connection Manager, which has the same keyboard shortcut for duplicating the current tab session.

Please let me know, how could we assign a different keyboard mapping for duplicating the session, as I don't want to change the `vim` bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Tools / Options / Hotkeys`:

[image: 1]

To redefine the keyboard shortcut for any operation, select the appropriate entry from the list and use the **New shortcut** box provided at the bottom.